# What is the significance ot the makecert -sk keyname option?

Tags: windows, certificate, x509certificate, makecert

I am using makecert.exe to create an RSA certificate and I am wondering what the significance is of this option? **-sk KeyName**

The documentation says "Specifies the subject's key container location, which contains the private key. If a key container does not exist, it will be created"

But I don't know what that means. Is it used as some kind of seed for creating the certificate? This is my current command line:

```
makecert.exe -r -sr LocalMachine -ss my -a sha256 -pe -sky exchange -n "CN=Mycert"
```

Under what circumstances might I want to specify a KeyName?

Comment: Stop using `makecert`, it is deadly outdated and officially deprecated: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386968(v=vs.85).aspx consider to use `New-SelfSignedCertificate` PowerShell cmdlet.

Comment: Still, do you know the significance of KeyName?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but don’t bother with deprecated stuff, it makes zero sense.